# What is wrong with the scope of this variable? jsfiddle

Tags: jquery

I have been fooling with this for a while and I can't seem to be able to use the variable `leavespace` in multiple functions. I've simplified the code to make it easier to read.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/T7f6L/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

var leavespace = '';
$(function() {

var nav_height = $(".nav").outerHeight();

var leavespace = nav_height - 10;

}); // end function


$(".link_scroll").click(function(event){        
 event.preventDefault();
$('.result').html('Var is: '+leavespace);

});

});
```

Why can't I use the var `leavespace`?

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/T7f6L/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

leavespace is in the scope of the defined anonymous function; you won't be able to use it outside of those

```
     {...}
```

braces.

In order to use it, inside the anonymous function- don't redeclare it as

```
 var leavespaces = my_height - 10;
```

Instead use

```
  leavespace = my_height - 10;
```

The reason for this is that in every scope, the interpreter will look in the symbol table object for the specific variable; if it has a declaration next to it (var variableName) then it will create a new symbol table object as long as none exist in the scope. When the scope is left, all the objects will be flushed from the symbol table. So the only leavesspace variable that the interpeter knows of it the one which hasn't been assigned to yet.

Please let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: So what do I change to be able to use it?

Comment: edited the post - please let me know if you have any questions!

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to redefine the variable leavespace in dom ready event. :

```
var leavespace = '';
 $(function() {
 var nav_height = $(".nav").outerHeight();
 leavespace = nav_height - 10;
}); // end function
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LKh97/)**

declaring variable again in dom ready limits its scope in the event itself. Which will always give you the globally declared(which is empty string in your case) value declared outside.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the var inside the function:

```
$(function () {
    var nav_height = $(".nav").outerHeight();
    leavespace = nav_height - 10;
}); // end function
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/T7f6L/1/)**

Having the `var` in there creates a new local variable scoped to only that function.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has function scope, so your line

```
var leavespace = nav_height - 10;
```

is in fact declaring a whole new variable called leavespace, that is scoped only inside your anonymous function

```
$(function() {

 //....Only scoped to here

});
```

This leaves the variable you declared outside of this function completely untouched, so remands an empty string.

If you want to affect the first variable you declared outside of the function, don't use `var`

eg

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var leavespace = '';
    $(function() {

        var nav_height = $(".nav").outerHeight();

        leavespace = nav_height - 10;

    }); // end function


    $(".link_scroll").click(function(event){        
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.result').html('Var is: '+leavespace);

    });    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You define the same variable twice so assigning the inner variable only

Also move the global variable out of the function, here is your working code

```
var leavespace = '';
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {


$(function() {

  var nav_height = $(".nav").outerHeight();

  leavespace = nav_height - 10;

}); // end function


$(".link_scroll").click(function(event){        
  event.preventDefault();
    $('.result').html('Var is: '+leavespace);

});

});
```

Answer (score -3):

modified working answer:

```
 var leavespace = '';
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      var nav_height = $(".nav").outerHeight();
      leavespace = nav_height - 10;
    $(".link_scroll").click(function(event){        
      event.preventDefault();
        $('.result').html('Var is: '+leavespace);

    });

    });
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9k47D/)

Comment: what about the down-votes? his leavespace variable wasn't updated, so i modified his code, to make it work.!! please leave a comment below explaining about the downvotes.